# How do you change the timeout in Apache2

Tags: apache, timeout

I've been searching how to change Apache2 timeout. The articles I found were old and referred to php.ini and httpd.conf. I found the answer and thought it would be good to have one on stack overflow so people could quickly find an answer that is not outdated.

Answer (score 0):

This [ubiq article](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-request-timeout-apache/) explains that there are now more than one conf file. The article says, "You will find the Apache server configuration file located at one of the following locations, depending on your installation."

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search for Timeout and you can read the Apache comment and set the timeout to what you desire. If you want to learn about the Keepalive settings typically after the timeout, there is a nice explanation in [I/O Flood](https://ioflood.com/blog/2020/02/21/what-is-apache-keepalive-timeout-how-to-optimize-this-critical-setting/).